# Append code to inherited class method

Tags: python, class, append

How would you append to the method of an inherited object? Say, for example:

```
class ABeautifulClass(GoodClass):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        # some code that will override inherited code
    def aNewMethod(self):
        # do something
```

Now I have inherited code from `GoodClass`, how would I append code to an inherited method. If I inherited code from `GoodClass`, how would I append to it, instead of basically removing it and rewriting it. Is this possible in Python?

Comment: Call the parent method, then do what you want to add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, invoking the superclass method must be done explicitly, via the `super` keyword. So it's up to you whether you do that or not, and where in your method you do it. If you don't, then your code will effectively replace the code from the parent class; if you do it at the start of the method, your code effectively appends to it.

```
def aNewMethod(self):
    value = super(ABeautifulClass, self).aNewMethod()
    ... your own code goes here
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using super

```
class ABeautifulClass(GoodClass):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        # some code that will override inherited code
    def aNewMethod(self):
        ret_val = super().aNewMethod() #The return value of the inherited method, you can remove it if the method returns None
        # do something
```

[Learn more about super here](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)